# Column Encryption Setting is encrypting a non-encrypted parameter when deployed to IIS, not from code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

The project is a WebAPI that calls various procs inserts and returns that contain encrypted data. Oddly, this works just fine when run from code but when I deploy to IIS the parameter is being encrypted by SQL. There are no config changes between code to deploy.

The parameter being passes is NOT an encrypted column; it's a PK, int ID field.

If I make a similar call that does not contain a parameter, it performs as expected. Encrypted columns return unencrypted.

If I make a call without Column Encryption Setting=enabled, the parameter is not encrypted and the call returns but obviously the encrypted column data returns as encrypted.

I'm using the following connection string in my web config from C#:

```
Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User Id=ServiceUser;Password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Column Encryption Setting=enabled;
```

And the Parameter is being added as a SqlParameter.

At this point, I can't tell if I'm missing something in code or if something isn't configured properly in SQL.

Comment: Wbich dbms are you using? (This isn't really related to the SQL _language_.)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Profiler 18 to monitor what I'm sending to SQL. I'm not sure if the issue exists code side or SQL side (like maybe something wasn't set up properly?) My DBA hasn't set something like this up before. I was hoping that somebody had heard of the situation I've been having and might point me in the right direction.

Comment: This will only happen if you are using this parameter against an encrypted column (even if it is also used against a non-encrypted column), because the driver automatically calls `sp_describe_parameter_encryption` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-parameter-encryption-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16